# Embeded youtube video gives UMG content message

Tags: html

I'm trying to embed a video from YouTube.  When I preview the page, I will get a black screen with the words "This video contains content from UMG.  Playback restricted on certain sites.  Watch on YouTube(link)."  The video did have copy written material, but has been removed and the video was uploaded again to YouTube.  I still get the same error.  Someone else has been able to upload the video on a live site.  I'm not running a testing server-not sure if this is part of the problem?

```
<'iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/3uIkI49uk8I?rel=0" 
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

The example code below has a video that explains how to remove the copyright restriction 
when I put in your youtube it came up with the UMG so try the steps in the video and the code snippet should work too.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>play youtube</title>
</head>
<'iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/lUq0lYmJ89c?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
<body>
  <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.`enter code here`
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'lUq0lYmJ89c',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```